# one to many mapping without any relation in tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i have two tables named as oc_users and oc_groups there is no specific relation between both the tables as shown below so, here i want to map each user with each group:

1)table 1: 
select uid from oc_users;

```
+-----------------+   
| uid             |    
+-----------------+   
| manesh@abc.in   |    
| pankaj          |    
| sumit           |    
+-----------------+
```

2)table 2: 
select gid from oc_groups;

```
+---------+    
| gid     |    
+---------+    
| qlc     |    
| qlc-web |    
+---------+
```

Then i want o/p like:

```
+---------+-----------------+    
| gid     | uid             |    
+---------+-----------------+    
| qlc     | manesh@abc.in   |    
| qlc     | pankaj          |    
| qlc     | sumit           |    
| qlc-web | manesh@abc.in   |    
| qlc-web | pankaj          |    
| qlc-web | sumit           |    
+---------+-----------------+
```

Comment: @JW:Hey will u please tell me how did you formatted above tables,since i was struggling to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
select * from oc_user , oc_groups ORDER BY gid, uidS
```

This will print all columns with `Cartesian multiplecation of rows.`

Comment: this is an old syntax of join.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `CROSS JOIN` (*new SQL Syntax: `ANSI SQL-92`*)

```
SELECT gid, uid
FROM   oc_users CROSS JOIN oc_groups
ORDER BY gid, uid
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d85dc/2)

Answer (score 0):

Using `CROSS JOIN(Cartesian Product Join)` will solve your purpose. For your information
A cross join that does not have a WHERE clause produces the Cartesian product of the tables involved in the join. The size of a `Cartesian` product result set is the number of rows in the first table multiplied by the number of rows in the second table.

So simply this will do,

```
SELECT gid, uid
FROM   oc_users CROSS JOIN oc_groups;
```

Always go for 'CROSS JOIN' syntax instead of giving nothing. Since this is ANSI format you can use it across database and it will be useful during migration also as you dont need to change anything in your query.

Hope this helps you!!